# Correct DNS settings for postfix

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, email-server

I'm currently planning my new mailserver and can't stop thinking about one simple thing: The DNS settings. Most MX records look like **mail.doomain.tld** or **mx01.domain.tld**. Are there any advantages of using a format like this or could I just use **domain.tld**?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter.

You must only be sure that the record value point to the correct IP, only technical reason to use something like **mail.example.com** instead of just **example.com** is because the mailserver and the webserver CAN be a different servers (with different IP).

Answer (score 2):

You also don't even need a "MX" Record, if no MX record is found it will default to your "A" record. So your mail server and domain name can be the same name if you want it to be. Check out [Unlock The Inbox](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/default/), if you're setting up a mail server for the first time, they have a lot of useful information.